# Unit test for static $app

Tags: yii2, codeception

I want to test a code:

```
public static function getFirstRole($userID) {
       $role = array_values(Yii::$app->getAuthManager()->getRolesByUser($userID));
       if (isset($role[0])) {
           $role = $role[0];
       } else {
           $role = Yii::$app->getAuthManager()->getRole('client');
       }

       return $role;
   }
```

My test is:

```
expect('First role should be client',
AuthManager::getFirstRole(1)->name)->equals('client');
```

When I runned this test then I get

> yii\base\InvalidConfigException: The "id" configuration for the
>   Application is required.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I used `use yii\codeception\DbTestCase;` instead `use tests\codeception\backend\unit\DbTestCase;`. Because it doesn't upload config with `id` for $app